# Unable to change vector elements using iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

int main(){ 
vector<float> test;
test.push_back(0.5);
test.push_back(1.1);
test.push_back(0.9);
vector<float>::iterator maxval = max_element(test.begin(), test.end());
vector<float>::iterator it;
for (it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
    *it = (*it)/(*maxval);
for (it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
return 0; }
```

The problem:

The last element (or in general all the vector elements past the element pointed to by the maxval iterator and including that element) do not change. Why does the maxval iterator *protect* the subsequent vector elements from being modified ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because maxval is pointing to `test[1]` and once you compute `0.9 / *maxval`, `*maxval` is actually `1.0`, this way `test[2]` stays unchanged.

You can copy maxval value to local float variable, to have last element changed:

```
float fmaxval = *maxval;
```

and below:

```
for (it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
    *it = (*it)/fmaxval;
```